# Djinni - Android Crash - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, djinni

very much stuck here I had the project working fine now for some reason every time i launch i get a crash. any help on this would be appreciated.

```
Process: com.amr, PID: 4185
                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load amr_android from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.amr-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.amr-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                           at com.amr.RandomRumbers.<clinit>(RandomRumbers.java:25)
                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the apk there is no native library for the specific processor type of the target device. You should check which one you have and provide the apk with the native library compiled for that type.

Comment: I tried that and checked all the versions but the output file is missing i believe in the libamr

Comment: Based on the exception, there should be a file like this in your project:
    lib/armeabi-v7a/libamr_android.so
Or replace "armeabi-v7a" with "x86" or whatever other architecture you're running on (emulator or device).